# Mongodb authenticating against local database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, database, nosql

I am trying to connect to a local instance of mongodb from a node application. But I can't seem to authenticate, it keeps trying to authenticate me through the local database instead of the admin database.

in my config file here is what I have

```
// mongodb config
config.mongodb.name = 'my_db_name';
config.mongodb.local.collection = 'my_db_name';
config.mongodb.username = 'user';
config.mongodb.password = 'pass';
config.mongodb.adminPrompt = false;
```

here is the error I am getting when I run the app in the node terminal

database authentication failed: db=local username=user workerPid=9921

in the mongo terminal I get this error

```
2016-04-28T12:21:30.931-0400 I ACCESS   [conn3] Successfully authenticated 
as principal vpoc on my_db_name

2016-04-28T12:21:30.500-0400 I ACCESS   [conn10] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for 
user on local from client 127.0.0.1 ; UserNotFound Could not find user user@local
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of MongoDB? Try taking node out of the equation, and connecting to MongoDB using the `mongo` shell. You most likely need to add the `--authenticationDatabase` flag.

Comment: im using 3.2.1, and I can connect using the mongo shell perfectly fine

Comment: You need to configure node to specify a database to authenticate against. Having a difficult time finding any documentation on this. Can you show how you're connecting to MongoDB?